# Display values stored in array while typing

Tags: angularjs

I want to show data stored in array while typing the same data based on alphabet. Now I got the data only after pressing enter button. My html code is shown below.

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput"name="freefield3" placeholder="add a tag" ng-model="vm.metadata.freefield3"
   uib-typeahead="tag for tag in states| filter:$viewValue" class="form-control"/>
```

In Angular controller

```
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas','bihar'];
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a very simple way

```
<input ng-model='key'></div>
<div ng-if="key">    
   {{array | filter : key}}
</div>
```

In this way as you write something in the input, you see your filtered array